# TweenAccessor for music.class in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been wondering: is it possible to use Universal Tween Engine in LibGDX to - for example - change the volume of a song? I wrote my own MusicAccessor with code similar to my SpriteAccessor, which actually works for Sprite.class, but when it comes to music objects - it always gets the same error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No TweenAccessor was found for the target
```

The thing is, I DO register my accessor by: `Tween.registerAccessor(Music.class,new MusicAccessor());` I'm quite sure it's actually being registered, as `System.out.println(Tween.getRegisteredAccessor(Music.class));` prints: `the.name.of.my.packages.MusicAccessor@14bb523`. Honestly, I'm stuck.

The music file itself is in .mp3 format and I load it by an asset manager.

So, my questions are: why the Tween Engine cannot correctly recognise the class of my music object? Is there a way to make it work or am I stuck with regular timers to change the volume over time? Would changing the format or loading the music file in a different way help?

Comment: Could you update with an example of the fix please.

Comment: The code is gone, but from what I remember all I had to do was adding `cast(Music.class)` while registering (?) the Music object for tweening. The method can be chained.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally haven't used Tween Engine myself yet, but I think it might be because `Music` is actually just an interface.

There are several implementations for the different backends and different file formats. For example `AndroidMusic`, `GwtMusic`, and three more implementations of `OpenALMusic` (they are all called `Music` and are located in the `com.badlogic.gdx.backends.openal.mp3/ogg/wav` packages). You could either register them all with your accessor, or you can use [`Tween.cast()`](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/source/browse/tween-engine-api/src/aurelienribon/tweenengine/Tween.java#455) which I found in the code, but not in the official JavaDoc of the tween engine. It might be only in the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, casting() worked. I must have overlooked that method, unfortunately.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie Can you please explain how you cast `Music` to a class??

Comment: I haven't used this library in a long time, so I won't provide a code sample, but all you have to do is add `.cast(Music.class)` on your tweening method invocations or manager registration. If I remember correctly, most of these methods could be easily chained, so adding a few casts is all you need.