# No TweenAccessor was found for the target

Tags: java, libgdx, tween

I have an issue implementing tweening in my libGdx program. My issue is similar yet different to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978847/tweenaccessor-for-music-class-in-libgdx). I am following a video guide on this and the code does look identical however I get the error `No TweenAccessor was found for the target` - I have tried looking online for solutions but none has worked and was mostly wrongfully setting the tween to the class.

Code:

```
public class SplashScreen implements Screen {

...

    private Sprite splash;
    private TweenManager tweenManager;

...

    @Override
    public void show() { 
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        tweenManager = new TweenManager();
        Tween.registerAccessor(SplashScreen.class, new SpriteAccessor());

        System.out.println(Tween.getRegisteredAccessor(SplashScreen.class));

        Texture splashTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/splash.png"));
        splash = new Sprite(splashTexture);
        splash.setSize(Constants.APP_WIDTH, Constants.APP_HEIGHT);

        Tween.set(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager); // This throws the error
        Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 2).target(1).start(tweenManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        tweenManager.update(delta);

        batch.begin();
        splash.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
...
```

Accessor:

```
public class SpriteAccessor implements TweenAccessor<Sprite> {



public static final int ALPHA = 0;

    @Override
    public int getValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
        switch(tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            returnValues[0] = target.getColor().a;
            return 1;
        default:
            assert false;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
        switch(tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            target.setColor(target.getColor().r, target.getColor().g, target.getColor().b, newValues[0]);
            break;
        default:
            assert false;
        }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
tween.SpriteAccessor@1b3a40d // note
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.RuntimeException: No TweenAccessor was found for the target
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.Tween.build(Tween.java:787)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.Tween.build(Tween.java:79)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.start(BaseTween.java:85)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager.add(TweenManager.java:61)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.start(BaseTween.java:98)
    at screens.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:36)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.simcas.game.RunGame.create(RunGame.java:12)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

As you can see (as in the linked question) the tween is set to the class as my print shows. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You made a sprite accessor so you can tween sprites. But you're registering it to a SplashScreen.class which makes no sense. Just follow http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/wiki/GetStarted

Comment: It is just poor naming but I do have an accessor (which I will edit into the post).

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just change Tween.registerAccessor(SplashScreen.class, new SpriteAccessor()); to Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());

Comment: Because i need the accessor to my splashscreen. I am doing the fading on the splash and not sprites. It's called SpriteAccessor due to poor naming, should have called it SplashScreenAccessor

Comment: Then don't you have to change TweenAccessor<Sprite> to TweenAccessor<Screen>? But then you wouldn't have 'Sprite target' in your accessor. You'd have a 'Screen target' and you'd only be able to access screen properties.

Comment: I just tried with no luck. The guy in the vid. guide has the same as i posted with no problems.

Comment: Well all you're trying to do according to your code is tween a sprite, not tween a screen. That's the intent of the two Tween.whatever lines. You're giving it a sprite to tween not a screen. So all you need is a Sprite accessor (which you already have). You're just trying to register it to a Screen which is wrong. You just need Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());

Comment: `splash` variable is a sprite btw, I'll edit that

Comment: yea that's what I'm saying. Did you try changing Tween.registerAccessor(SplashScreen.class, new SpriteAccessor()); to Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. Could you make an answer so I can credit you please?
I thought i had to reffer to the class I was in. I am sorry I didnt understand at first!

Comment: Cool, I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register your SpriteAccessor to the Sprite class not to the SplashScreen class. The tweens you are performing are on a sprite not on a screen.

Change

```
Tween.registerAccessor(SplashScreen.class, new SpriteAccessor());
```

to

```
Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());
```