# Using UniversalTweenEngine with LibGDX music

Tags: libgdx, tween

### Short question...

How do I correctly use `UniversalTweenEngine` with the `Music` class in LibGDX?

---

### Long question...

I've encountered a problem with using `UniversalTweenEngine` and the `Music` class in LibGDX. I have a `MusicAccessor` that implements `TweenAccessor` like so:

```
public static final int VOLUME = 0;

@Override
public int getValues(Music target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
    switch(tweenType) {
    case VOLUME:
        returnValues[0] = target.getVolume();
        return 1;
    default:
        assert false;
        return -1;
    }
}

@Override
public void setValues(Music target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
    switch(tweenType) {
    case VOLUME:
        target.setVolume(newValues[0]);
        break;
    default:
        assert false;
    }
}
```

first I used it like this:

```
Tween.registerAccessor(Music.class, new MusicAccessor());
myMusicInstance.setVolume(0);
Tween.to(myMusicInstance, MusicAccessor.VOLUME, 1f).target(1).start();
```

Which gave me an error saying that

> No TweenAccessor was found for the target

I read some on the problem and saw people having the same issue, and the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978847/tweenaccessor-for-music-class-in-libgdx) question told me that I had to use `.cast(Music.class)` as well, so i changed it to this:

```
Tween.to(myMusicInstance, MusicAccessor.VOLUME, 1f).cast(Music.class).target(1).start();
```

which no longer gives me the error. The snag with this is that it doesn't actually tween any value! I've added `TweenCallback`s and done `System.out.println("text")` in the `TweenAccessor`'s methods, and found out that they aren't being called. So how am I supposed to do for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your problem and managed to fix it, so here is a solution.
First of all you need an instance of `TweenManager`. Then don't forget to start your music (it won't start by itself). Your `MusicAccessor` class is ok, so no need to change anything there. The final code snippet: 

an instance field

```
private TweenManager tweenManager = new TweenManager();
```

constructor (or wherever you used it)

```
Tween.registerAccessor(Music.class, new MusicAccessor());
myMusicInstance.setVolume(0);
myMusicInstance.play();
```

and then in render:

```
tweenManager.update(delta);
Tween.to(music, MusicAccessor.VOLUME, 1f).cast(Music.class).target(1).start(tweenManager);
```

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: It seems like I had just forgotten to add my TweenManager to the start() method, silly me!